# Cannot get and set value to BehaviorSubject in angular

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to add a boolean value to a BehaviorSubject. However, when I try to console log it says that it is undefined. What I'm doing wrong?

This is how I declare it.

```
isDesktopWidth: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
```

And this is how I use it

```
changeSideBarWidth() {
if (this.innerWidth > 767) {
  this.isDesktopWidth.next(true);
} else {
  this.isDesktopWidth.next(false);
}

}
```

And then in the ngOnInit

```
this.changeSideBarWidth();
console.log(this.isDesktopWidth.value);
```

But it doesn't display anything in the console. Only an error saying that

> Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assigned the type of the variable `isDesktopWidth` but have not initialized it. Try

```js
isDesktopWidth = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

`BehaviorSubject` needs to be initialized with a value. If you wish to create without an initializer, use `Subject`. In that case you could use

```js
isDesktopWidth = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Another difference between them is `BehaviorSubject` holds a value. So it will return the current value it holds as soon you subscribe to it. `Subject` does not hold the current value. When you subscribe to it, you will not receive a value till it emits the next one.

Using `.value` property on a unemitted `Subject` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelD, I have another problem which doesn't change the value at all...It is always true, why is this happening?

Comment: Based on your condition, I'd assume `this.innerWidth` variable might always be greater than 767.

Comment: Actually is not, if I will console log the innerWidth, it changes the screen size number. And when it is below 767 it consoles log whatever I put in that else statement.

Comment: Then try subscribing to it. In `ngOnInit()`, do `this.isDesktopWidth.subscribe(r => { console.log(r); });`